# Solving differential equation $ \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{3e^y}-1 $ results in strange result?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was trying to solve this differential equation but I think I may be making a mistake.

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{3e^y}-1 $$

First I multiply both sides by $3e^y$, then bring everything to one side and factorise

$$ 3e^y\left(1+\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=0$$

Giving values for both y and dy/dx as

$$ y=0, y=-x+c $$

This is not the right answer based on an online ODE solver, and I am sure I did something wrong. Is it possible to solve the equation this way?

The expected result given $y(0)=0$ is $$y=\ln\left(\frac{1+2e^{-x}}{3}\right)$$

Comment: $3e^0\left(1+\frac{\mathrm{d}0}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)=3\ne0$

Comment: $y=0$ is clearly not a solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your work, you should have $3e^y(1+\frac{dy}{dx})=1$.

Hint: let $z=e^y$, $dz/dx=z\cdot dy/dx$ and solve the linear ODE in $z$,
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{1}{3}-z$$
such that $z(0)=e^0=1$, then go back to $y=\log(z)$.

Comment: Oh my god, that is so embarassing ... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A direct approach:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac13e^{-y}-1=\frac{1-3e^y}{3e^y}\implies-\int\frac{-3e^y}{1-3e^y}dy=\int dx\implies\ln|1-3e^y|=-x+C\implies$$

$$\implies1-3e^y=Ke^{-x}\implies e^y=\frac{1-Ke^{-x}}3\implies\ldots$$

and then use the initial condition $\;0=y(0)\;$ to get $\;K=-2\;$ .